# OSError: cannot load library ‘libngspice.so’

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation, ubuntu-18.04

Good afternoon community, I am writing to you because I have encountered the following error trying to simulate the following filter that appears in the documentation.

[enter link description here](https://pyspice.fabrice-salvaire.fr/examples/filter/low-pass-rc-filter.html)l

The error is as follows.

```
2020-05-23 00:45:37,954 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared.new_instance - INFO - New instance for id 0
2020-05-23 00:45:37,955 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared._load_library - WARNING - Set locale LC_NUMERIC to C

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-6-475d4280ae1b> in <module>()
----> 1 simulator = circuit.simulator(temperature=25, nominal_temperature=25)
      2 analysis = simulator.ac(start_frequency=1@u_Hz, stop_frequency=1@u_MHz, number_of_points=10,  variation='dec')

8 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cffi/api.py in _load_backend_lib(backend, name, flags)
    825         if first_error is not None:
    826             msg = "%s.  Additionally, %s" % (first_error, msg)
--> 827         raise OSError(msg)
    828     return backend.load_library(path, flags)
    829 
OSError: cannot load library 'libngspice.so': libngspice.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libngspice.so'
```

I have installed all the dependencies, although I have run out of ideas, I am starting in the world of programming, however, they asked me for a job to simulate filters in the university. I need your help, if possible, a lot of fat in advance
the characteristics of my system are ubuntu 18.04 , python 3.6.2, pyscpice 1.4.2
I already tried

```
apt-get install libngspice0 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libngspice0-dev
```

Comment: `libngspice.so` is provided by the package 1. Debian, Ubuntu: `libngspice0-dev` ... and 2. Fedora, CentOS: `libngspice-devel`

Comment: I already tried it with the various ways to install packages in ubuntu occupying apt, however it cannot find the package giving the following error E: Unable to locate package libngspice0-dev libngspice0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, the library ngspice not installed in the system.
Please clarify the version of the operational system, because the dependencies problem sometimes really hard.
Perhaps, the lines below could help:

- Debian/Ubuntu package installation `sudo apt install libngspice0`
- Redhat/Centos package installation `sudo yum install libngspice`

Comment: sorry for the lack of information the characteristics of my machine are as follows ubuntu 18.04 python 3.6.2 pyspice 1.4.2, try to install libngspice0 by apt I get the following message E: Unable to locate package libngspice0 If you have another way to install it, let me know, however I will investigate a way I have already tried installing the repository that is in git, however I get very large errors

Comment: Did you try running `apt-get update` before running `apt-get install`?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. Ubuntu 18.04 does not contain the libngspice0 package, that added to Ubuntu 19. Ubuntu 18.04 contains the package ngspice, but unfortunately without the library. So the build from source is an option for that system. Or you can try to upgrade the system to the next LTS Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Let's say I can't change from 18 to 20 liters, however I will look for other solutions

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and this worked for me:

> > sudo apt update 
> > sudo apt install libngspice0-dev

NOTE: I tried even installing libngspice and libngspice0, but nothing worked.